# Can I customize zip/postal code validation option after selecting a product and before proceeding to Add to Cart Option?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, pincodes

I need to customize **zip/postal code** validation in the Magento product page after selecting a product it should proceed to pin code validation, once pin code gets validated it has to give me add to cart.
I am new to magento development so it would be great if somebody could guide me to integrate this feature.

This is the code that I included in

**/app/design/frontend/mywebsite/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
<div class="product-essential">
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product,array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>        
<div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
    </div>

     <div class="product-img-box">
<div class="product-name">
                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-shop">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="price-info">
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            </div>
        <div class="extra-info">
        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>

    <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <div class="short-description">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_askquestion_link') ?>


<?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                    <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
        <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
            <div class="add-to-box">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo  $this->getChildHtml('catalog_product_view_sellerinfo');?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true,  true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
    </div>

    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
    <?php endif;?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

    productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
        if(this.validator) {
            var nv = Validation.methods;
            delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
            delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
            // Remove custom datetime validators
            for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                    delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                }
            }

            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                if (url) {
                    this.form.action = url;
                }
                this.form.submit();
            }
            Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
//]]>
</script>
</div>
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you want to use pincode checker like flipkart?

Comment: Are you using any extension for check product availability on certain zip codes ??

Comment: please post the extension.. how you have use that extension

Comment: Yes exactly I wanted to make it like flipkart

Comment: I haven't used any extension just hard coded it in view.phtml the location of my file is path: /app/design/frontend/mywebsite/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml. check the code I have just attached my view.phtml file

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need that? It's just going in the way of a smooth UX in my experience.